# Find the degree of a field extension and proving polynomial irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I'm looking for the degree $|\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+2\sqrt2}): \mathbb{Q}|$ and I found that $\sqrt{3+2\sqrt2}$ is a root of $f(x) = x^4-6x^2+1$ but I have trouble proving that this polynomial is irreducible. (tried the substitution trick but doesn't work, eisenstein doesn't work either)

Comment: Hint: $3=\sqrt{2}^2+1^2$.

Comment: $f$ is not irreducible. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3084462/degree-of-the-extension-mathbbq-sqrt3-2-sqrt2) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1619071/588038) duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

It's reducible:
$$
x^4-6x^2+1= (x^2 - 2 x - 1) (x^2 + 2 x - 1)
$$

Comment: Also note, $\sqrt{3+2\sqrt{2}}$ is a root of the polynomial $x^2-2x-1$.

Comment: Indeed, $\sqrt{3+2\sqrt2}=1+\sqrt2$.